# How do I restrict vsftpd access to a certain directory?

Tags: ftp, vsftpd

I would like to give a user access to our ftp server. Not to everything, just the directory he needs to work in.

When he logs in he should be directed to /var/www/hisdir and not be able to go outside it. I've read about restricting a user to his home directory but not to other directories.

If this is not possible with vsftpd is there maybe something thats more configurable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

restrict access to the home folder and then mount the folder the user needs to work in under his home directory.

add the line to fstab

```
/var/www/hisdir     /home/username/somefolder name          none        bind     0   0
```